# Cannot get my vue accordion to open programatically

Tags: vue.js, accordion, bootstrap-vue

A quick use case. User views a line on one screen and wants to see what invoice it was involved with. Upon entering the invoice screen, flicks to the right date range (this part works fine) to show the list of invoices for that month. I would like the accordion the invoice overview is in to open automatically for them. So even though there may be 5-6 on the page, the one that the line is involved with opens.

```
     <div role="tablist">
        <b-card no-body v-for="invoice in invoices" v-bind:key="invoice.id">
          <b-card-header header-tag="header" class="p-2" role="tab">
            <b-row
              v-b-toggle="'invoice-' + invoice.id + invoice.customerid"
              class="payment-header pt-0"
            >
               // Contents
            </b-row>
          </b-card-header>
          <b-collapse
            :id="'invoice-' + invoice.id + invoice.customerid"
            :ref="'invoice-' + invoice.id + invoice.customerid"
            accordion="my-accordion"
             role="tabpanel"
          >
                        // Invoice Overview Contents

         </b-collapse>
        </b-card>
       </div>
```

This is the template code. All works fine in normal circumstances, user can click each open as required.

When the page opens, the relevant Guids are grabbed from the route and used to formulate the v-b-toggle value for

`v-b-toggle="'invoice-' + invoice.id + invoice.customerid"`

From inspecting the DOM, the value is evaluated correctly.

The code snippet:

```
<script>
    load () {
        var collapseId = 'invoice-' + props.id + response.props.customerid
        console.log('collapseId', collapseId)
        this.$root.$emit('bv::toggle::collapse', collapseId)
    }
</script>
```

It appears that this is the code that does not work, i.e. the accordion does not open. The collapseId evaluates correctly. I don't seem to be getting anywhere in terms of getting it working, I am assuming as it's involved in a v-for.

Comment: Can't you just add a `v-model` on the `<b-collapse>` component to control its visibility?

Comment: Sorry, not entirely sure what you mean. I did google around, but just adding v-model="visible" didn't seem to do much other than throw an error to my console.

Comment: I'm refering to this: https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/collapse#v-model-support. The component accept a v-model property binding to a boolean that controls its open/close state.